# CSS3 background images adapt to different browsers

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adapt the three background images for different resolutions (mobile, tablet and computer screen in 1920 x 1080). How should I do?.[enter link description here](http://luscoefusco13.es)

Comment: Refer here:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `media-queries` in your CSS files.
You can read more about how `media-query` works [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) but the following CSS is a general guide to how you'd want to manage your queries.

```
/* Mobile screens */
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    #background-image{
        background-image: url('imageMobile.jpg');
    }
} 

/* Larger than phone. Tablet-sized. */
@media (min-width: 401px) {
    #background-image{
        background-image: url('imageTablet.jpg');
    }
}

/* Desktop-sized. */
@media (min-width: 920px) {
    #background-image{
        background-image: url('imageDesktop.jpg');
    }
}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #background-image{
        background-image: url('imageHDDesktop.jpg');
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in your CSS - not in a `media-query`, you would define all the other properties of your container element, and then the `media-queries` will choose the `background-image` that best fits their size.

**Edit:** A few years back, when `media-queries` were introduced, people used to use `max-width` exclusively. Now there is a newer responsive design approach that uses `min-width` instead, using the nature of CSS' 'cascade' to apply and then overwrite each successive rule until the final query is the correct one. This way, smaller devices won't have to load the media queries for devices larger than their own screen, which turns into a performance boost on older mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I send you the main.css file to add the variations?.

Comment: @BraisRemeseiro Here on StackOverflow we encourage developers to learn by trying! CSS is very easy to learn and there are excellent tutorials available on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp) if you're not confident.

Give the code a try, and see if you can't learn a little something new along the way!

Comment: I tried and I am completely lost to add the code as you explain it, please...I will give you a donation of 15$.

Comment: And How I do if I want to modify three background images?.

Comment: /* Containers */

 .container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 }

 .container.\31 25\25 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1800px;
  min-width: 1440px;
 }

 .container.\37 5\25 {
  width: 1080px;
 }

 .container.\35 0\25 {
  width: 720px;
 }

 .container.\32 5\25 {
  width: 360px;
 }

 .container {
  width: 1440px;
 }

 }

Comment: Please, help me, I am lost.

Comment: @BraisRemeseiro If you're in the business of programming or web design/development, there's really no excuse for being unfamiliar with a language. CSS is exceptionally easy to learn, so do yourself a favor and undertake just a few minutes' online training in CSS. You'll laugh at challenges like this once you understand even the basics.

Edit: my code should be very easy to integrate for anyone with even basic knowledge of CSS. You really need to learn these basics to become a better programmer/student/employee.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your patience. I am trying this code without results:

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
 
 #background-image{
        background-image: url(../../images/intro.png);
    } 

  .container.\31 25\25 {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1700px;
   min-width: 1360px;
  }

  .container.\37 5\25 {
   width: 1020px;
  }

  .container.\35 0\25 {
   width: 680px;
  }

  .container.\32 5\25 {
   width: 340px;
  }

  .container {
   width: 1360px;
  }

 }

Comment: And..if I want to do with three images?.

Comment: I am lost...please help.

Comment: Please, Can you help?.